# Best focal length option for architectural photography using MFT systems?

Tags: architecture

One of the tricky subjects for photographers using MFT systems are buildings. How do we get rectilinear building shots? Shift / Tilt lenses are no-go's in digital because oblique light does not interact with the sensor correctly, which is why MFT lenses are (or are supposed to be) telecentric.

So, for rectilinear shots we are pretty much limited to perspective adaptations in post processing. So, the question is: **what focal lengths will work the best for this?**

If we use a fisheye and get close to the building and tilt up, then we have both a shift and tilt problem. An alternative is to go far away, then fisheye ground level, so there is no tilt, but we lose half the image into the ground. We can do the same procedures with telephoto lenses, but have to back up even more.

No having much experience with perspective correction in post, I am wondering what the best strategy is, and how that strategy relates to tilt vs shift correction?

Comment: Have you considered the Laowa 7.5mm F/2? but even with this, you are still limited to the distance from where you can get the entire building in frame. if however, you can get far enough back, then go further back leaving loads of space on either side of the building to straighten the converging lines in post and not to cut the main subject.

Comment: You don't need really tilt for ultra-wide-angle perspective correction; only shift is needed. Tilt alters the plane of focus, which generally isn't needed with an ultra-wide. Hugin (https://hugin.sourceforge.io) is free and will do perspective correction. I'll second the Laowa 7.5mm ƒ/2 for architecture, but the Olympus 7-14mm ƒ/2.8 is more flexible (and more expensive). I have both, and find the Laowa doesn't fill the frame the way I need it to. You want LOTS of pixels for software perspective correction!